# How to call ajax function on each dyanamically added row in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Ajax function is as below

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function getStudentDetails() {
            var userName = document.getElementById("getName").value;
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                cache : false,
                data : {name:userName},
                url : "get_project_details.php",
                success : function(student_details) {
                    var resArr = JSON.parse(student_details);

                    document.getElementById("pname").value = resArr[0];                       
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

And I am using Datatable with below function

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 10) {                     
        // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;


        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

            // tooltip code for each row



             // re-instantiate tooltip after the new ones are added since there is no eventhandler attached to them. (calling tooltip function here)
        //$onChange=getStudentDetails();
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();     

        }
    }
    else
    {
         alert("Allowed maximum items per indent is 10. Please raise one more indent if required");

    }
}
```

When I Select Project Number, project name is appearing in next field, but after adding another row Ajax function getStudentDetails() is not working

Comment: Do you get any error in the console ?

Comment: No I am not getting any erros

Comment: How do you summon that function? Please notice that you're using `getElementById('getName')` so if you're duplicating that element it's no longer a valid `id` (since it should be unique).

Comment: is it work if i take as getElementByName?